# Dangling pointer.. in a book?

Tags: c

I probably missed something but just wanna ask.. I found this code in the book Advanced Linux programming:

```
    char* get_self_executable_directory ()
    {
      int rval;
      char link_target[1024];
      char* last_slash;
      size_t result_length;
      char* result;
      /* Read the target of the symbolic link /proc/self/exe. */
      rval = readlink (“/proc/self/exe”, link_target, sizeof (link_target));
      if (rval == -1)
        /* The call to readlink failed, so bail. */
        abort ();
      else
        /* NUL-terminate the target. */
        link_target[rval] = ‘\0’;
      /* We want to trim the name of the executable file, to obtain the
      directory that contains it. Find the rightmost slash. */
      last_slash = strrchr (link_target, ‘/’);
      if (last_slash == NULL || last_slash == link_target)
        /* Something strange is going on. */
        abort ();
      /* Allocate a buffer to hold the resulting path. */
      result_length = last_slash - link_target;
      result = (char*) xmalloc (result_length + 1);
      /* Copy the result. */
      strncpy (result, link_target, result_length);
      result[result_length] = ‘\0’;
      return result;
    }
```

And my question is, doesn't this function return a dangling pointer?

Comment: Good choice in books, by the way.

Comment: By the way, @andrew, the thing to do if an answer answers your question isn't just to say "thank you" in comments, it's to give it an upvote and a checkmark.  And if it helped but wasn't the complete answer, at least give it an upvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It returns a pointer and expects that deallocation will be done in client code. When you see functions that return pointers you always have to ask yourself (well really the author...) whether or not ownership of the memory (that is the responsibility to deallocate it) passes to the function's client and if so how exactly it should be freed.

Comment: Good point about the ownership of the memory.  That's something I always try to document in comments in the function declaration and the function definition (and hope that the two comments stay in sync).

Comment: +1 for mentioning responsibilities for memory management down the line.

Comment: Ok, interesting comments about memory deallocation but does this answer the question ? I'm a bit confused ! Actually I'm confused also regarding the question. Why would you think this piece of code creates a dangling pointer

Comment: Razvan: because i thought there's no difference in this regard if you allocate memory staticaly or dynamicaly.. didn't know that if it's malloc-ed, it stays allocated even after the func returns..

Comment: The **entire point** of `malloc` is that the obtained object has dynamic storage duration, i.e. persists until you call `free` on it. If not for this property, the `malloc` function would have essentially no purpose.

Comment: @andrew ok, now it makes sense

Answer (score 5):

No -- it allocs memory , and returns it.